# I'm trying to sum the number of rows that are not nothing. IF the row count is 2, but LastNAme (row 2) is Nothing, i need to return 1

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get an accurate count of borrowers on a loan. The system I'm working in automatically creates 2 rows for each application we enter. I want to return the sum of rows that are not nothing.

I'm looking at the borrower last name. So if we have two applications on the loan file, our system automatically creates 4 rows. However, the borrower last name field in row 4 is nothing. I want to return 3 since the borrower last name field in rows 1, 2 and 3 is not nothing

I'm fairly new to VB.NET and am trying to use a For Loop to count each row when the last name is not nothing.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim BrwrCT = GetFieldRowCount(144)

For i = 1 To BrwrCT
    If GetFieldValue(144,i) IsNot Nothing
    Return 1 + BrwrCT
    Else Return BrwrCT
End If
Next i
```

For this example, the loan file has 3 borrowers and the result should be returning 3, however, I am receiving 5 (BrwrCT + 1)

Comment: Where is your data? In a DataGridView, a DataTable, a 2-dimensional array? In your title you are asking for sum. A sum normally applies to a column of numbers. You cleared things up in the text of the question asking for count.

Answer (score 0):

In your `For/Next` loop you set the max loop to be `BrwrCT` and then inside of the loop you are modifying the value of that same variable `BrwrCT`.  You should avoid modifying the loop range inside of the loop doing that range.  You should also not use the `Return` statement inside of the loop unless you actually want to leave that loop immediately without performing all of the iterations of that loop. In your sample code, this loop would only ever execute once and then immediately exit (aka `Return`).

I recommend creating a second variable that will have the count you are looking for:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim BrwrCT = GetFieldRowCount(144)
Dim totalBorrowers As Integer

For i = 1 To BrwrCT
    If GetFieldValue(144,i) IsNot Nothing Then
       totalBorrowers += 1
    End If
Next i
Return totalBorrowers
```